# looping through a matrix with a function

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I'd like to perform this function on a matrix 100 times. How can I do this?

```
v = 1
m <- matrix(0,10,10)

rad <- function(x) {
  idx <- sample(length(x), size=1)
  flip = sample(0:1,1,rep=T)
  if(flip == 1) {
    x[idx] <- x[idx] + v
    } else if(flip == 0) {
      x[idx] <- x[idx] - v 
      return(x)
}
}
```

This is what I have so far but doesn't work.

```
for (i in 1:100) {
  rad(m)
}
```

I also tried this, which seemed to work, but gave me an output of like 5226 rows for some reason. The output should just be a 10X10 matrix with changed values depending on the conditions of the function.

```
reps <- unlist(lapply(seq_len(100), function(x) rad(m)))
```

Comment: `for (i in 1:100) { m <- rad(m) }` ?

Comment: This seems to generate only 1 run and not 100

Comment: I don't undestand what you want to obtain... a list of 100 matrices ?

Comment: I want to have a single matrix in the end of the same dimensions that I started with. The values inside the matrix should change based on the function

Comment: Are you aware that when you pass a variable as parameter to a function the value is copied, so when you change the parameter inside the function, the source does not change ? Hence, if you want to modify `m` you need to use the code in my first comment ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I got it.

The `return` statement in your function is only inside a branch of an `if` statement, so it returns a matrix with a probability of ~50% while in the other cases it does not return anything; you should change the code function into this:

```
rad <- function(x) {
  idx <- sample(length(x), size=1)
  flip = sample(0:1,1,rep=T)
  if(flip == 1) {
    x[idx] <- x[idx] + v
  } else if(flip == 0) {
      x[idx] <- x[idx] - v 
  }
  return(x)
}
```

Then you can do:

```
for (i in 1:n) {
  m <- rad(m)
}
```

Note that this is semantically equal to:

```
for (i in 1:n) {
  tmp <- rad(m) # return a modified verion of m (m is not changed yet) 
                # and put it into tmp

  m <- tmp      # set m equal to tmp, then in the next iteration we will 
                # start from a modified m
}
```

Comment: This is closer to the final answer but the output is a bunch of different matrices. 

The final output should just be updating a single matrix with new values and not making a new matrix every iteration.

Comment: I more question. How could I tell the function to NOT subtract 1 from the value in the cell if the final value is < 0?

Comment: Also, how can I add a loop in rad to make it + or - 4 times instead of just once. However, I need to keep size=1 and not increase it.

Comment: For the first question, you could modify the `if` statement like this: `if(flip == 1 && x[idx] >= 0)`, for the second one, could you be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

When you run rad(m) is not do changes on m. 
Why? 
It do a local copy of m matrix and work on it in the function. When function end it disappear.
Then you need to save what function return.
As @digEmAll write the right code is:

```
for (i in 1:100) { 
    m <- rad(m) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop here. The whole operation can be vectorized.

```
v <- 1
m <- matrix(0,10,10)


n <- 100 # number of random replacements

idx <- sample(length(m), n, replace = TRUE) # indices
flip <- sample(c(-1, 1), n, replace = TRUE) # subtract or add
newVal <- aggregate(v * flip ~ idx, FUN = sum) # calculate new values for indices
m[newVal[[1]]] <- m[newVal[[1]]] + newVal[[2]] # add new values
```